# How can I get the data type of a switch statement with the javaparser?

Tags: java, types, switch-statement, javaparser

How can I get the data type of a switch statement with the Java parser? Currently with getSelector() I can only get it as a Name expression which does not have the type.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't know, but you could look at this and see if it helps.
[Oracle Switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)